# Adding an extension method to a record with unit of measure

Tags: f#, inline, units-of-measurement, f#-4.0

Why does this work:

```
type Money = 
   { Amount : decimal } with

   member inline m.gotMoney : bool =
      m.Amount > 0M
```

but this doesn't

```
type MoneyUOM<[<Measure>]'currency> = 
   { Amount : decimal<'currency> } with

   member inline m.gotMoney : bool =
      m.Amount > 0M<_>
```

Instead, i get `error FS0339: The signature and implementation are not compatible because the type parameter in the class/signature has a different compile-time requirement to the one in the member/implementation`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's because you're using `decimal` instead of `float`.  The issue is that `0M<_>` is not considered a generic value, while `0.0<_>` is.

Comment: @kvb This answers the "why?" part of the question, in a way.  Please convert it to an answer so you could get a well-deserved up-vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DecimalWithMeasure` is useful here. For example, this works for me:

```
type MoneyUOM<[<Measure>]'currency> = 
   { Amount : decimal<'currency> } with

   member m.gotMoney() : bool =
      let zero = LanguagePrimitives.DecimalWithMeasure<'currency> 0M
      m.Amount > zero
```